# Spring 3 to Spring 4 (Java 7 to Java 8) - AspectJ compilation error : "cannot access ApplicationEventPublisherAware"

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am in the process of upgrading a project from Java 7 to Java 8 (and with it Spring 3 to Spring 4).

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
DomainSecurityAspect.java:[88,39] error: cannot access ApplicationEventPublisherAware
```

The code it is complaining about is:

```
@Around("target(com.mycompany.automation.domain.framework.DomainEntityImpl+) && !execution(* equals(..)) && !execution(* hashCode()) "
        + "&& !execution(* toString()) && !execution(* get*(..)) && !execution(* is*(..)) && execution(public * *(..)) "
        + "&& !within(com.mycompany.iecc.data.automation.domain.aop.DomainSecurityAspect)"
        + "&& !execution(* com.mycompany.iecc.data.automation.domain.framework.BaseObject.*(..))"
        + "&& !execution(* com.mycompany.iecc.data.automation.domain.framework.DomainObjectImpl.*(..))")

public Object domainObjectInstanceExecution(final ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable    
{
    if (this.securityInterceptor == null)
    {
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }

    final AspectJCallback callback = new AspectJCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public Object proceedWithObject()
        {
            try
            {
                return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
            }
            catch (Error e) 
            {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (RuntimeException re) 
            {
                throw re;
            }
            catch (Throwable th)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(th);
            }
        }
    };

    // Compiler complains about this line
    return this.securityInterceptor.invoke(thisJoinPoint, callback);

}
```

### Software Versions I am using:

Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_66)

Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE

Aspectj version 1.8.8

cglib-nodep version 3.2.0

*Note: This compiles OK when it uses Java 7 with Spring 4, but when compiled with Java 8 it gives that compilation error.*

Comment: Which line is line 88?

Comment: // Compiler complains about this line - line below 88

    return this.securityInterceptor.invoke(thisJoinPoint, callback);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error was in my POM - to fix this I had to change the scope from **runtime** to **compile**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```